# selecting random number of records from ms access using vb.net and then navigating these records randomly

Tags: vb.net, random, record

I want to create an exam application in vb.net
Which will have a question, 4 options and an answer

now I have 400 questions with its options and answers in my database.

the test should be of 100 marks.

I should ask the questions randomly to the examinee

But how?

I got the query below after googling it

```
"SELECT * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"
```

But I don't know the meaning of that query especially the meaning of LIMIT 1

If somehow the above query is fetching data randomly from the database then what should I do when user gives the answer of the first question. I mean what should be the code for displaying the second question to the user?

Comment: LIMIT 1 means limit the result set to 1 row.  So in your case, you could use LIMIT 100.  However, I don't think MS-Access selects LIMIT.

Comment: However, I would recommend getting all the questions from the database in one read, and then have the program select 100 random questions.

Comment: But how ? I don't understand

Comment: How to get the records from the database?  How to select 100 random records from a group of 400 in the program?  What kind of platform - ASP.NET, MVC, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: How to select 100 random records from a group of 400 records and how to change the question when user gives the answer to the current question. My Platform is ASP.NET

Comment: Here's a general outline:  Create a class that holds the question information.  Create a List that holds all the instances of that class (the 400 questions from the database).  Use `Math.Random` to select 100 random questions, and put them in another list.  When the program starts, show the first question.  When the user answers, show the next question in the list of 100.  Continue until done.

Comment: Tip: Use dictionary so that you dont get two identical questions in the same test.